# ActionMailer link host failing rails 3.1 and heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, actionmailer

I am including links in my emails sent from my heroku app. I followed the ActionMailer railscast and had everything running fine in development, but when using heroku/sendgrid, the links are being sent without a host. For example, instead of http://www.reelify.com/users/2 th link is just http://users/2

Here is my setup_mail.rb in initializers:

```
require 'development_mail_interceptor'

if Rails.env.production?
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => 'XXX',
  :password       => 'XXX',
  :domain         => 'heroku.com'
}
else
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "reelify.com",
  :user_name            => "XXX",
  :password             => "XXX",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
end

ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "reelify.com"


ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(DevelopmentMailInterceptor) if    Rails.env.development?
```

I've also tried adding this line to my production.rb but it is commented out now while I test:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {  :host => 'reelify.com' }
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess you're putting paths in your email and not urls:

```
users_path => /users
users_url => http://localhost:3000/users
```

In outgoing communication (email etc), always ensure you're using `_urls`

Comment: ah I see, that is exactly what I was doing. I had a link_to helper and was using "@user" as the href. Thank you